# Applying Master's Theorem with f(n) = 2^n

Tags: algorithm

I am trying to apply the Master's Theorem to a recurrence of this type:

> T(n) = T(n/2) + 2^n

However, f(n) = 2^n doesn't seem to fit any of the three cases described in the master's theorem, which all seem to have base n instead of base 2. How can I solve a recurrence of this type, could anyone please help ? Thanks.

Comment: This is an invalid case for applying master's theorem , as simple as that . try substitution method as in one of the answrs below or try recursive tree method. And please always provide terminating condition with the recurrence relation.

Comment: @CARBON Terminating condition is irrelevant if the recursive case only appears linearly, I think.

Comment: @G.Bach But its not the linear case, here.

Comment: @CARBON The recursive part is "T(n/2)", which is linear.

Comment: @G.Bach May be I don't understand you but as far as recursion is concerned its logarithmic not linear.

Comment: @CARBON I'll try those methods, thanks. Actually, I am trying to solve the Master Theorem Practice questions listed over [here](http://people.csail.mit.edu/thies/6.046-fall04/) The guy had successfully applied the theorem on it though the details are not mentioned, so I supposed that Master Theorem could be applicable. This question is number 3 on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If none of the cases of the theorem applies, then the theorem won't solve your recurrence. It can't solve every single recurrence out there.

---

To address your issue: what you get by repeatedly substituting the recursive case is T(n) = 2^n + 2^(n/2) + 2^(n/4) + ... + 2, and since there are log n many terms to add up, you end up with something below 2^(n+1), so in total you're in Θ(2^n).

Comment: But doesn't 2^n represent the non-recursive portion of the equation ?

Comment: Yes. This means that the first recursion dominates all others, which happens. Remember that factors, constants and lower-order terms are elided in Big-O Notation.

Answer (score 0):

We can take log on both sides and solve. It will fall in case 3 of Master's theorem.